# Why is this code giving me an output of 5?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

The goal of this code is to double each number in the array. I was trying to mimic the map() method. But that is not important. What I am wondering is why this code gives me an output of 5 while I did not console.log it. Then when I run it again it keeps adding 5 to a variable I am not aware of?

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const doubleNumbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
  doubleNumbers.push(numbers[i] * 2)
}
```

Comment: How are you detecting the output? The provided code example doesn't output anything.

Comment: The shown code will give an error as numbers2 is not defined

Comment: sorry, I fixed it now. doubleNumbers was called numbers2 which is not defined indeed.

Comment: If you are running this in your browser console, then the `5` is coming from the last `.push()` which returns the length of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Array.push returns the new length of the array:

```js
let arr = [];

console.log(arr.push('something')) // Should output 1
console.log(arr.push('something else')) // Should output 2
```

You didn't log anything, but if you run code in the console it will print the outcome of the last statement.

Comment: For instance if I wrote 1+1 as the final line of this code, the output would be 2. Now I know and understand, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: the push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

If you run this in the developer console, it will log the last returned result.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your Code output is okay

```
     const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
     const doubleNumbers = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i+=1) {
         doubleNumbers.push(numbers[i] * 2)
      }

      console.log(doubleNumbers)
```

Maybe You console the length of array

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you aren't giving the entire context here?
What is numbers2 anyway? You declare a new array, doubleNumbers, but don't use it?

```
doubleNumbers.push(numbers[i] * 2)
```

should work just fine I believe.

Comment: My mistake, I changed it now. Should be doubleNumbers indeed.